# When WebRTCPeer disconnects/closes connection it is never propagated to the server

Tags: webrtc

I am using an implementation of https://github.com/webrtc for my app. I have a networking stack implemented that uses WebRTC. The issue I am seeing is that when the client exits the app it closes the PeerConnection object, and the server gets a state change from `kIceConnectionConnected` to `kIceConnectionDisconnected` which is good and all but I would expect to see `kIceConnectionClosed`. The problem with the disconnected state is that if your network is spotty then you can intermittently get `kIceConnectionDisconnected` state which may heal itself afterward. And I don't want to close the connection.

The question is: how do I as a server guarantee that the client has quit the app and that I can tier down the connection on the server side right away?

Edit:
According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-data-channel-13#section-6.7
there should be a channel reset that happens on both sides, how would server knows that it needs to reset the channel?

Comment: ICE connections don't get closed, they just time out. Can you listen for DTLS alerts which show that DTLS considers the session to be terminated?

Comment: I am not 100% on how everything suppose to work in the first place.
Is STLS state similar or related to RTCPeerConnection?

Comment: It seems that you need peer connection state, but not ICE connection state: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/api/peer_connection_interface.h#192
AFAIK, kClosed state you would get when you call close method for that peer (explicitly or by destroying its instance). And when remote peer is closed, the other peer would go to kDisconnected. So, in your case, on the server side you should manually close the peer. The most obvious way to notify the server about client exiting is to send a message through signaling.

Comment: @ArtemSuprunov Cool, what exactly means "to send a message through signaling"? Could you elaborate on that part?

Comment: @kitten_woof Signaling - communication channel which is used for sending offers, answers, candidates etc. between the peers. It's up to you how exactly implement such protocol, it's not described by WebRTC. That could be webscokets or raw tcp, or whatever else. The idea is that the client during quitting should send sort of "bye" message, and on the server side after this message is captured - call close() for the peer that is associated with this client.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got what I had to do now.

Comment: Reviving this thread @ArtemSuprunov what is "bye" package is somehow not delivered?

Comment: It depends on your signaling protocol. For example, if it uses ping pong then in case of response timeout the client might be considered as disconnected.